# How to drawRect on top of normal UITextView?

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-graphics

How can I draw on top of a normal UITextView? For instance, I have a custom UIView class that sets the cornerRadius to 5 and the background color to [UIColor greenColor];

```
@implementation ChatBubbleTextView
-(id) initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder {
    self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder];
    if (self){
        self.layer.cornerRadius = 5;
        self.layer.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor].CGColor;
    }
    return self;
}

@end
```

But as soon as I add drawRect method, it makes my UIView blank. Is there a way I can have both the normal drawRect and my own implementation of drawRect?

I've also tried

```
-(void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect{
    [super drawRect:rect];
}
```

The interface:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ChatBubbleTextView : UITextView

@end
```

Comment: Can you please show the interface of your custom class.

Comment: drawRect is a default method when you will create custom UITextview, shall I know what exactly you want to achieve, question seems like not understandable what you want.?

Answer (score 0):

For some reason `self.layer.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor].CGColor` will work if there is no drawRect. However, when there is a drawRect, it will not work. You must use `[self setBackgroundColor:[UIColor greenColor]`